# Meteor .helpers function parameter

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is it possible to have pass a parameter from my template to a .helpers function parameter? I am trying the code below but I am always getting the error shown below. Thanks

```
Template.documentUpdate.helpers({

    getDocID: function(dCode){      
       return docsIDArray[dCode];
    }
});
```

in template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="docID" name="docID" value="{{getDocID(1) }}">
```

Error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: No such function: getDocID
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, try this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="docID" name="docID" value="{{getDocID 1}}">
```